# using Directive to SqlHelper is not working in VS2008

Tags: .net, asp.net, namespaces

I used visual studio 2005, in that I have created a class and created namespace for that. And in aspx.cs I am writing in above class using sqlhelper; it works. But I am getting an error in 2008 when I doing same thing. In 2008 already it provides namespace to class that not in 2005

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are simply missing a reference to ent-lib (assuming by "sqlhelper" you mean the MS application blocks example). Add that reference, and your `using` directive should start working. If you have *changed* your ent-lib version, note that "sqlhelper" is obsolete. I believe this was replaced by `Database` (and `SqlDatabase` etc).

(this should not be taken as a *recommendation* to use ent-lib; quite the opposite - I am not a fan ;p)

Comment: You can also use the SqlHelper class file on its own and avoid the payload of Ent Lib :)

Comment: Ya ,I added sqlHelper class file in App_Code folder in vs2008.Still I getting error intype or namespace missing.

Comment: @Swati - please post the *exact, copy-pasted* error so that we can see it. Also, make sure that the namespace is correct, and that the class you have added is marked to *compile* (rather than to just sit there)